# Difference between $y'y=x-1$ and $y'=\frac{x-1}{y}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't understand the difference (if there is one) between these differential equations in terms of the intervals in which solutions are defined:

$y'=\frac{x-1}{y}$

$y'y=x-1$

I mean it is just the same equation but, while in the first one the condition $y\neq 0$ is obviously necessary, in the second one for $y=0$ I get $x=1$. What does that mean?
Are there solutions that cross the x axis?

I've a similar doubt for the $x$. Considering these two equations

$y'=\frac{y}{x-1}$

$(x-1)y'=y$

In the first one I must obviously impose $x\neq 1$ while in the second one I have to do that because then I must divide for $x$ right?

Thanks a lot in advice

Answer (score 1):

This is true for all fractions, not just differential equations. If $xy = n$, then we can rearrange to get $y = \frac{n}{x}$, but only for $x \neq 0$. Thus, the functions are the same for all but a finite number of points when converting multiplications to divisions. If you require the excluded points then you must either leave the function in multiplicative form or point out the value of the excluded points as special cases, i.e. a piecewise function

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This solves the problem for $x$ but my doubts are mainly about tue fact that, looking at the first two equation I can't understand why $y$ must be different from $0$ since to solve the equation I don't have to do a division at all

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso In the first example, $y(0) \implies x=1$ is absolutely true. The problem with dividing on both sides is that you remove this case... thus, when we solve for $y'(x)$ we lose information at $y=0$ (the two functions **are not the same**... they just differ at a finite number of points). Now, if this is a problem you can resort to the two methods I list above, or you can leave the problem as you first give it. Doing the division is often needed when working with the derivative though, as we care more about what it does in general rather than at a specific point.